# HAR vs SequenceFile

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

Both HAR and sequence files solving small files problem for HDFS.

I am interesting in understanding when one should prefer one over the other?

As far as I know, HAR is just about compression and grouping. But sequence files also support block compression. Sequence files are key-value, but what that fact gives me if they are block compressed. Any difference?